# ServiceBus message handler using Windows.Azure.ServiceBus (5.2.0) fails to deserialise body stream using DataContractSerializer NET 4.6.1

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I'm using Windows.Azure.ServiceBus (5.2.0) to receive and handle an Azure ServiceBus message. As part of this I need to access the message body as a string to create a checksum. The code is as follows:

```
if (messageBody.StartsWith("@"))
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new(typeof(string));
    using XmlDictionaryReader xmlDictionaryReader = 
    XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(brokeredMessage.GetBody<Stream>(), XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
    messageBody = (string)serializer.ReadObject(xmlDictionaryReader);
}
```

If I create a StreamReader and read the text from the stream as UTF8 it comes out as `@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/��{"Prop1":null,"Prop2":null,"Prop3":null,"Prop4":null,"Prop5":null}`

The error at `(string)serializer.ReadObject(xmlDictionaryReader)` is "Expecting element 'string' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered 'None'  with name '', namespace ''. "

What I'm wanting is to get the JSON from the payload as a string. The BrokeredMessage is being created with a JSON string as the body before being posted to a Topic that is subscribed to and handled by the code above.

Comment: Try   XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(message.Body.ToStream(), XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);

Answer (score 0):

As [HarshithaVeeramalla-MT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16630207/harshithaveeramalla-mt) suggested could you please try to use the below code in place of your code.

```
XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(message.Body.ToStream(), XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
```

[image]